# Rails tests (minitest) cause PostgreSQL syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

So whenever I run a test, Rails seems to be attempting to insert nothing into my PostgreSQL database... causing a syntax error. What could possibly cause this? For some context, this happens with every test, regardless of how simple or complex. For example:

```
class PlayerTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "should not save empty player" do
    assert true
  end
end
```

And then I see the following error message:

```
Error:
PlayerTest#test_should_not_save_empty_player:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "players_venues" () VALUES ()
```

Also, `players_venues` is a many-to-many join table between `players` and `venues`. This problem does not occur outside of tests. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If any more code is required please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Check (and/or share) the fixtures for `players_venues` and the `test_helper.rb` for anything funky. If it happens for all tests, I suspect it has something to do with the test setup...

Comment: @jdno Thanks mate, I found the problem thanks to this. I'm adding an edit to explain. Appreciate the help man.

Comment: @Cœur fixed! Sorry I'm still pretty new to SO

Comment: @Cœur New to actually having a question solved though haha, all my other questions have gone unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually figured this out. It turns out Rails generates empty fixtures like so:

```
one: {}
# column: value
#  
two: {}
# column: value
```

When you run the tests it attempts to insert nothing! Thanks heaps to jdno for giving my a hint to look into the fixtures. Bloody champion.